# How to get Interquantile list of values in R

Tags: r, range, quantile

Take any random dataset:

```
data = rnorm(100)
```

I want to get a list of the largest 5% of values in this data. If I try:

```
quantile(data, .95)
```

...then I get the single value at the 95th percentile. If I try:

```
quantile(data, probs=c(1, .95))
```

...then I get only two values: the largest value in the dataset and the value at the 95th percentile. If I try:

```
quantile(data, 1 - .95)
```

...then I get the single value at the 5th percentile. If I try:

```
quantile(data, >.95)
```

...then I get a syntax error message.

**How do I get a *list* of all values within a given quantile range?** (In this case how do I get a list of all values that fall between the 100th and 95th percentiles?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use basic subsetting:

```
data[data>quantile(data, .95)]
```

Technically, this is a "numeric vector" in R and not a "list", which is a different data type, but I assume it's what you want.